# How to control Dialog Box in Autocad from c#?

Tags: c#, autocad

I am running a command in Autocad2012 using Autocad API through C#. After running the command It's showing me a Dialog Box and I want to control that Dialog Box through C# also but unable to do it. Its a simple create file Dialog Box.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you'd like to control the dialog box?  Is it a native AutoCAD dialog or is it one you created?

Comment: If you explain exactly what you're trying to do, including the commands you're using and how you want to control the dialog (move, change values, close, etc.) it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at input simulator: http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/
You can use it to simulate key presses (and other things)

Comment: Sorry but something better is required.

Comment: Even though its not a precise answer but it helped me to solve my problem. Rest other answers are still apreciated